# C# regex remove special characters but leave alphanumerics

Tags: c#

```
return Regex.Replace(source, "[^a-zA-Z0-9% @$\"!#%&'()*+,./:;<>=?-]", string.Empty);
```

How to allow also characters like ČĆŽPŠĐ or German characters with umlauts,...

Answer (score 2):

You could use character classes as shown [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/20bw873z.aspx).

A simplified version of your code: `new Regex("[^\\p{L}0-9 ]").Replace("this is a test ČĆŽPŠĐ ä 244 $%^&*", String.Empty);`

This Yields: `this is a test ČĆŽPŠĐ ä 244`.

`\\p{L}` in this case denote the character sets which marks letters across different languages.

Answer (score 2):

Just try this :

```
Regex.Replace(source, "[^a-zA-Z0-9% @$\"!#%&'()*+,./:;<>=?\u0100-\u01FF-]", string.Empty);
```

German is : `U+0100` -> `U+01FF`

Answer (score 1):

'Č', 'Ć', 'Ž', 'Š' and 'Đ' are all part of the Unicode category 'Letter, Uppercase'. You can use `\p{..}` to match against characters from a specific Unicode category, where `..` is the (short) category name.

For example, `\p{Lu}` matches all characters in the 'Letter, Uppercase' category, and `\p{Ll}` matches all characters in the 'Letter, Lowercase' category.

So just replace `a-z` with `\p{Ll}` and `A-Z` with `\p{Lu}` (just make sure you escape the `\`, or use a verbatim string literal for your expression).

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/20bw873z%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#CategoryOrBlock for more information, and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/20bw873z%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#SupportedUnicodeGeneralCategories for all supported categories.